# Call from Skype with front speaker

Tags: audio, skype

My phone has two speakers, one in front that is used during normal call, and one in the back (the "loudspeaker") that is used to play music and in hands-free mode. When I'm using Skype for Android, it uses the loud speaker. This is very uncomfortable if I want to make Skype call in public place. I could use headphones and mic, but I don't always have them with me.

Is there a way to call on Skype just like normal voice call, with the front speaker?

Eventually, any other app would be good, that can make calls to PC using any of major protocols (Skype, GTalk, MSN), and that uses front speaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you **should be able to switch between Loudspeaker and Earpiece like this in the screenshot at the bottom** while in a call. On my Samsung Galaxy 3 running a custom 4.0.3 ROM, it's working fine.

But after searching on Skype Forums I found this - [Speaker only on Android device](http://community.skype.com/t5/Android/Speaker-only-on-Android-device/td-p/1322)

Looks like a lot of people are having the same issue from initial releases of Skype for Android. Devices and OS are different in each case, so there really is no solution for users other than to wait for a fix from Skype.

You should perhaps look for alternative apps like these-

1. Fring ([Fring Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fring))
2. SIP  ([SIP for Android](http://www.voipvoip.com/android/))
3. GTalk for Android app. (Supports Video/VoIP from Android 2.3 onwards). See here - [xda-develoeprs GTalk w/Video & Voice for 2.3.3 roms](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1062980)

[image]